# NextJs Webpack asset/source returns JSON as a string

Tags: json, webpack, next.js, bundle, webpack-5

Looking for some help to understand what is going on here.

### The Problem

We are using a translation service that requires creating JSON resource files of copy, and within these resource files, we need to add some specific keys that the service understands so it knows what should and should not be translated.

To do this as simple as possible I want to import JSON files into my code without them being tree shaken and minified. I just need the plain JSON file included in my bundle as a JSON object.

### The Solution - or so I thought

The developers at the translation service have instructed me to create a webpack rule with a type of assets/source to prevent tree shaking and modification.

This almost works but the strange thing is that the JSON gets added to the bundle as a string like so

```
module.exports = "{\n  \"sl_translate\": \"sl_all\",\n  \"title\": \"Page Title\",\n  \"subtitle\": \"Page Subtitle\"\n}\n";
```

This of course means that when I try and reference the JSON values in my JSX it fails.

### Test Repo

- https://github.com/lukehillonline/nextjs-json-demo
- NextJs 12
- Webpack 5
- SSR

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Download the test repo and install packages
2. Run `yarn build` and wait for it to complete
3. Open `/.next/server/pages/index.js` to see the SSR page
4. On line 62 you'll find the JSON object as a string
5. Open `.next/static/chunks/pages/index-{HASH}.js` to see the Client Side page
6. If you format the code you'll find the JSON object as a string on line 39

### Help!

If anyone can help me understand what is going wrong or how I can improve the webpack rule to return a JSON object rather than a string that would be a massive help.

Cheers!

### The Code

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,

  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.content.json$/,
      type: "asset/source",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Title.content.json

```
{
  "sl_translate": "sl_all",
  "title": "Page Title",
  "subtitle": "Page Subtitle"
}
```

Title.jsx

```
import content from "./Title.content.json";

export function Title() {
  return <h1>{content.title}</h1>;
}
```

pages/index.js

```
import { Title } from "../components/Title/Title";

function Home({ dummytext }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title />
      <p>{dummytext}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const dummytext = "So we can activate SSR";

  return {
    props: {
      dummytext,
    },
  };
};

export default Home;
```